# Retrieve the commit hash

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently working on a deployment script to run as part of my GitLab CI setup. What I want is to copy a file from one location to another and rename it.

Now I want to be able to find what commit that file was generated with, so I'd like to add the hash of the commit to it.

For that to work I'd like to use something like this:

```
cp myLogFile.log /var/log/gitlab-runs/$COMMITHASH.log
```

The output should be a file named eg.

```
/var/log/gitlab-runs/9b43adf.log
```

How is this possible to achieve using GitLab CI?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is `CI_COMMIT_SHA` (formerly `CI_BUILD_REF` in GitLab 8.x and earlier)  which one of the predefined variables.

All predefined variables are listed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Comment: `CI_BUILD_REF` was replaced by `CI_COMMIT_SHA` in 9.x

Answer (score 59):

In your example you used the short git hash that you would get with the predefined variable `CI_COMMIT_SHA` by building a substring like this:

```
${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}
```

or by using the short sha directly

```
$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

Comment: Gitlab 11.7 added `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` for this.  See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: Look like `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` spit out an 8 character long hash. Whereas `git rev-parse --short` give an 7 character long one.

Answer (score 19):

Since [GitLab v11.7](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#predefined-environment-variables) you can use `$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` which returns the first eight characters of `CI_COMMIT_SHA`.